# Why are "Paas" (aka cloud hosting) so expensive these days?

Tags: paas, cloud-hosting

As a developer, I love the new hosting platform raising lately, such as Pantheon, Platform.sh or Acquia Cloud.

Automated workflows and task runner based on Git and simple YAML files are great features.

However, those platforms are quite expensive for one who simply wants to host a personal website.

I'm wondering why are `PAAS` (aka `managed hosts`) so expensive these days compare to other hosting solutions such as `shared` or `VPS`. The later have seen their price being reduced significantly in the last few years.

In my opinion, the price of a hosting service should be mainly based on...

- the amount of traffic
- the disk usage

... not on the technology sustaining the platform.

Comment: Seems more suitable for https://economics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I actually tried to find a more suitable place before posting this here but I haven't found Economics Stackexchange. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure this is a stackoverflow kind of question (more of a Quora?). Still, I am going to try and have a stab at answering this as I may provide some insight (I work for Platform.sh):

What services like ours propose is a bargain of time vs money. Basically, if we can save 100 hours a month worth of work for a skilled engineer that is $10,000 of value delivered to a company.

Now in order to achieve this companies like ones you have cited invest heavily in R&D...  but also in support and ops people that are around 24/7. 
The time spent on the project doesn't disappear, it gets shared between anonymous/invisible people. You may not see it, but its there. The time you did not spend on updating the Kernel or a PHP version... the time you did not spend on defending against a vulnerability. Someone spent that time (it is shared between many, many projects and rolled-up into the global price.

... and  there is also a lot of "invisible infrastructure" that you don't see as the resources assigned to your specific project.

I think all three providers you cited offer multiple development/staging clusters (in our case 3 staging clusters). So when you see 5GB there are probably 20GB allocated...

If you were to install and run *all* the software that is necessary to run your single project **at the same conditions**... well you will see CPU, memory and storage costs pile-up quite rapidly: Redundant storage nodes, storage for backups, monitoring and logging systems, multiple fire-wall layers, a build farm ... and the coordination and control servers needed to run all of that ...

So this is very much apple and oranges.

Often when you work on a side/personal project, you don't have resources other than your time. So of course this kind of trade-off may be less appealing. You may think : well I just need the CPU, I am a competent SysAdmin, I don't need scaling and I don't need monitoring, nobody would scream if my blog is down ...  I am doing this by myself and I don't need multiple development environments... and you might very well be right...

I don't think providers as the ones you have cited are a fit for every type of possible project. And none of us were put in a magic cauldron at our birth. Everything that we do can be replicated. Well, if you spend enough time and resources on that...

I hope this answer gives you some clarity to why they can not possibly cost the same as bare-bones hosting.

Comment: It does give some clarity. Thanks a lot for taking the time to write this answer.

So, I understand Paas companies are mainly focused on BtoB - not BtoC - to be economically viable. Fair enough.

I regret that they can not propose much affordable "personal" plans.